# SQL server and patindex unspected result

Tags: sql-server, patindex

I'm trying to verify phone numbers with NANP format.

I'm using this code

```
 patindex('+1[2–9][0-9][0-9][2–9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', n)
```

But not works as expected, some numbers that should be valid (like +14104536330) not match with the expression.

I have created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b8b38/3) with the sample code.
What is wrong in my patindex expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copied your string to a hex editor, and the `[2-9]` show as:

```
+1[2â9][0-9][0-9][2â9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

The hex code between 2 and 9 is `E2 80 93`, which is [UTF-8 for "en dash"](http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128).  So the problem is basically that you've entered a funny version of a dash.  This can happen when you copy/paste out of a Microsoft AutoCorrect environment, like Outlook, Word or Excel.  AutoCorrect will silently upgrade your dashes to good looking dashes.

Comment: Just for completeness might be worth mentioning that the pattern then gets treated as a set (I.e matches 2,9, or en dash) rather than a range.